# Excel VBA objsnmp.set strange things

Tags: excel, vba, snmp

I use the objSNMP.get method in Excel VBA without any problems.

I'd like to use the objSNMP.set method, but unfortunately it's not that easy. According to the [website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/print/isnmp-set), it should work similarly to get, with the difference that there is one more parameter: the value to be sent.

If I try the official way:

```
objSNMP.Set ("43.18.1.1.2", OIDValue)
```

[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rG9Ew.png)
I get the message "Compile error: Syntax error".
I found another solution that works conditionally. Namely as follows (it can be seen commented out in the picture):

```
randomVarName = objSNMP.Set("OID", Value)
```

For example:

```
temp = objSNMP.Set(".1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.68.1.2.2.1.2." & PortNum, 21)
```

**In this case, the code runs without error.** This is interesting because I haven't found any official information about this anywhere. Somewhere deep in the recesses of the internet, I only found this possible solution some time ago.

If, on the other hand, I do not enter the value directly, but write the name of a variable there (e.g. VLANNum),

```
temp = objSNMP.Set(".1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.68.1.2.2.1.2." & PortNum, VLANNum)
```

I receive an error message. [Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHOVr.png)
It doesn't matter if the type of the variable is not declared, string or integer. I also tried several different cell types in Excel, but nothing changed.

The error message is:

> Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)':
>
> The requested SNMP operation attempted to modify a variable, but
> either a syntax or value error occurred.

Based on the above, I cannot insert the value read from the excel table at the end of the "objSNMP.Set" method in such a way that it can send the value. I could only solve the task if I create 4094 different "objSNMP.Set" lines and select what is necessary from among them. Not very efficient.

Comment: Yep, the message is translated to english in the description. The MS VBA 7.1 is English, but the message (part) is Hungarian. I assume that it is because the OS and Office are Hungarian.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the solution. The value transferred with the variable works in the following form:

```
objSNMP.Set ".1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.7.9", CInt(x)
```

Where **x** is the variable.